# Where can I find the source of `r.element` for a rails project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, view

I'm debugging a legacy rails project, and have some tricky problems on view rendering. Now I have a "user.json.rep" view, and it's content is like:

```
r.element :user, @user do |u|
  r.element :id, u.id
  r.element :name, u.name
end
```

I want to read the source of the `r.element`, but I don't know where are they from and which gem I should looked into. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Could it be [Representative](https://github.com/mdub/representative) or [Representative View](https://github.com/mdub/representative_view)?

Comment: Thank you, it's this one: https://github.com/mdub/representative/blob/7e1bb763f1e4ba4f7ad665c714c9a11f9379345d/lib/representative/json.rb#L24

Comment: Please approve my answer :)